# Finding Path/Route Between two points on MapKit in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

I am trying to find the path between two locations on Mapkit. All I have is two locations. Now I have to find the exact path between these points and draw a line between these points using MapKit. I have gone through several examples in which they are using .csv files. In that .csv file they have stored the latitude and longitude values of the full path and drawing line based on those values.

But here I am trying to draw a line without knowing the path. So is there any way to find the path dynamically and draw a line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below is the code to finds path & draws line between two locations.

To implement below class:

```
_mapRecord = [[PSMapDirection alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 49.0, 320.0, 411.0)];
[self.view addSubview:_mapRecord];
```

MapDirection.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "RegexKitLite.h"

@interface MapDirection : UIView<MKMapViewDelegate> 
{    
    MKMapView* mapView;
    NSArray* routes;    
    BOOL isUpdatingRoutes;
}

-(void) showRouteFrom: (MKAnnotation*) f to:(MKAnnotation*) t;

@end
```

MapDirection.m

```
#import "MapDirection.h"

@interface MapDirection()
-(NSArray*) calculateRoutesFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) from to: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) to;
-(void) centerMap;

@end

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self != nil) 
    {
        mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
        [mapView setDelegate:self];
        [self addSubview:mapView];      
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine: (NSMutableString *)encoded 
{
    [encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [encoded length])];
    NSInteger len = [encoded length];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSInteger lat=0;
    NSInteger lng=0;
    while (index < len) 
    {
        NSInteger b;
        NSInteger shift = 0;
        NSInteger result = 0;
        do 
        {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do
        {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        NSNumber *latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5];
        NSNumber *longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5];
        //printf("[%f,", [latitude doubleValue]);
        //printf("%f]", [longitude doubleValue]);
        CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]];
        [array addObject:loc];
    }   
    return array;
}

-(NSArray*) calculateRoutesFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) f to: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) t 
{
    NSString* saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", f.latitude, f.longitude];
    NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", t.latitude, t.longitude];

    NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr, daddr];
    NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];
    //NSLog(@"api url: %@", apiUrl);
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    NSString *encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];   
    return [self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]];
}

-(void) centerMap
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    CLLocationDegrees maxLat = -90.0;
    CLLocationDegrees maxLon = -180.0;
    CLLocationDegrees minLat = 90.0;
    CLLocationDegrees minLon = 180.0;
    for(int idx = 0; idx < routes.count; idx++)
    {
        CLLocation* currentLocation = [routes objectAtIndex:idx];
        if(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude > maxLat)
            maxLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        if(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude < minLat)
            minLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        if(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude > maxLon)
            maxLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        if(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude < minLon)
            minLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    }
    region.center.latitude     = (maxLat + minLat) / 2.0;
    region.center.longitude    = (maxLon + minLon) / 2.0;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;

    region.span.latitudeDelta  = ((maxLat - minLat)<0.0)?100.0:(maxLat - minLat);
    region.span.longitudeDelta = ((maxLon - minLon)<0.0)?100.0:(maxLon - minLon);
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

-(void) showRouteFrom: (MKAnnotation*) f to:(MKAnnotation*) t 
{   
    if(routes) 
    {
    [mapView removeAnnotations:[mapView annotations]];
    }

    [mapView addAnnotation:f];
    [mapView addAnnotation:t];

    routes = [self calculateRoutesFrom:f.coordinate to:t.coordinate];
    NSInteger numberOfSteps = routes.count;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[numberOfSteps];
    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numberOfSteps; index++) 
    {
        CLLocation *location = [routes objectAtIndex:index];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
        coordinates[index] = coordinate;
    }
    MKPolyline *polyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numberOfSteps];
    [mapView addOverlay:polyLine];
    [self centerMap];
}

#pragma mark MKPolyline delegate functions
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay 
{
    MKPolylineView *polylineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    polylineView.strokeColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    polylineView.lineWidth = 5.0;
    return polylineView;
}

@end
```

Sample Map Route for **starting points - "41.967659,-87.627869" and destination points - "41.574361,-91.083069**"

[image: Map Route]

Comment: This google API can't be used to provide step by step navigation. It also can't be used to print the routes over any map that ain't googles, so this won't be valid anymore for the iOS6 version. Anyway it's the best approach. I'm using something very similar for the same purpose.

Comment: HI iApple.. Its not working for me, its shows error at this line NSString *encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];  ...    my api url: http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=41.967659,-87.627869&daddr=41.574361,-91.083069

Comment: my apiResponse is {tooltipHtml:" (210 mi / 3 hours 41 mins)",polylines:[{id:"route0",points:"}cc_Gra{uOc@|AnA|@JZGbA??dDrB??uApM??bAb@ZZn@hARl@Hn@hC`b@Av@`@`G??l@E??PWhF{@JKtBC|Fo@dHyA|FoBtBa@`EWzOGdASjBq@na@yRhPeHbA

Comment: Can you paste your route, the starting point & the destination point?

Comment: @"41.967659 , -87.627869"      @"41.574361, -91.083069".. This is my start point and end point

Comment: I have just uploaded image showing the route given route info by you. Google api will be something like, http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=41.967659,-87.627869&daddr=41.574361,-91.083069. Verify it with your generated string.

Comment: my app crashes at this point NSString *encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];

Comment: what class is this #import "RegexKitLite.h"??

Comment: You can download it from,http://svn.cocoasourcecode.com/MGTemplateEngine/RegexKitLite.h
http://svn.cocoasourcecode.com/MGTemplateEngine/RegexKitLite.m

Comment: Ya i got it :). Finally its working like charm :). Thanks to everyone :) :)

Comment: Is there a way to get the `RegexKitLite` using ARC ?

Comment: @Lucien - I have already provided link for the same in the third last comment.:)

Comment: Hum yes I downloaded both the files but I got like 17 errors like _ARC forbids use of…_. So that's why I wanted some `RegexKitLite` supporting ARC. I'm still wrong ? :/

Comment: don't listen to @Thedude folks, this code works perfectly fine on iOS6 and iOS7, I tested it myself.. +1 to the author :)

Comment: @abbood I did not said the code does not work. I said the approach is not valid because of the use of google maps api. This solution uses MapKit, and since iOS6 mapkit does not use google's maps, it uses Apple's maps. If you bother to read the google API documentation for the directions API ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/ ) which this answer is using: "The Directions API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without displaying a map for which directions data was requested is prohibited."

Comment: @Thedude your point is well taken.. but then why didn't you share your solution with the rest of us?

Comment: @abbood Because I'm using a private system I'm not allowed to share.

Comment: @abbood - Thanks for your update. If I'm not forgetting, initially iOS 6 was released on September 19, 2012 and the question & solution was discussed about a month prior!

Comment: @Thedude do you mean to say you are using a proprietary solution for this problem? Or are you saying you figured it out, it's just that you used that code in a commercial/private project and so you can't share it with us?

Comment: @abbood The second one. Anyway, you could check this question and answer at stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753580/routing-data-for-mkmapkit-in-ios6 . They suggest to use MapQuest's Open Directions API. Cheers

Comment: Is this coding be used for iOS5

Comment: Can u please explian what happens in decode polyline method, or else any tutorial for that.

Comment: What is the base class of regexkitlite

Comment: @chandru - I suggest you to visit http://icodeapps.blogspot.in/2011/04/google-map-directions-api-objective-c.html for "Google's proprietary polyline & level encoding".

Comment: Ya, thank U, I have refered it, Well, can use regexkitlite in iOS5

Comment: Is there a way to get the RegexKitLite using ARC?                      As I am getting many errors like ARC forbids use of….

Comment: Is there any way to find time duration between source point to destination point?

Comment: @AliRaza - Please refer following apple's documentations. 
1.https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKRoute_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKRoute/expectedTravelTime
2.https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW5

Comment: this api current doesn't woriking.

Answer (score 7):

Here The way in which I am able to draw direction between two points(Location).

---

> > First of all download GoogleMap sdk from [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases) link and integrate into your application.

Now API key required and you can create as par given guidelines on [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#the_google_maps_api_key) link.

Below are Code that draw direction on google map between two location.

---

```
-(NSArray*) calculateRoutesFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) f to: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) t {
NSString* saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", f.latitude, f.longitude];
NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", t.latitude, t.longitude];


NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false&avoid=highways&mode=driving",saddr,daddr]];

NSError *error=nil;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error: &error];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary * dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

return [self decodePolyLine:[self parseResponse:dic]];
}
- (NSString *)parseResponse:(NSDictionary *)response {
NSArray *routes = [response objectForKey:@"routes"];
NSDictionary *route = [routes lastObject];
if (route) {
    NSString *overviewPolyline = [[route objectForKey:
                                   @"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"];
    return overviewPolyline;
}
return @"";
}
-(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine:(NSString *)encodedStr {
NSMutableString *encoded = [[NSMutableString alloc]
                            initWithCapacity:[encodedStr length]];
[encoded appendString:encodedStr];
[encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"
                            options:NSLiteralSearch
                              range:NSMakeRange(0,
                                                [encoded length])];
NSInteger len = [encoded length];
NSInteger index = 0;
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSInteger lat=0;
NSInteger lng=0;
while (index < len) {
    NSInteger b;
    NSInteger shift = 0;
    NSInteger result = 0;
    do {
        b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (b >= 0x20);
    NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1)
                      : (result >> 1));
    lat += dlat;
    shift = 0;
    result = 0;
    do {
        b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (b >= 0x20);
    NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1)
                      : (result >> 1));
    lng += dlng;
    NSNumber *latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5];
    NSNumber *longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5];
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:
                            [latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]];
    [array addObject:location];
}
return array;
}
- (void)loadMapViewWithDirection {

float lat = 23.050671;
float lng = 72.541351;

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:lat
                                                        longitude:lng
                                                             zoom:10];

GMSMapView  * mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 75, 320, self.view.frame.size.height-kHeaderRect.size.height) camera:camera];
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;


float sourceLatitude = 23.050671;
float sourceLongitude = 72.541351;

float destLatitude = 23.036138;
float destLongitude = 72.603836;

GMSMarker *sourceMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude);
marker.map = self.mapView;

GMSMarker *destMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(destLatitude, destLongitude);
marker.map = self.mapView;

self.mapView.delegate = self;

   [self drawDirection:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude) and:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(destLatitude, destLongitude)];


[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
}
- (void) drawDirection:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)source and:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) dest {


GMSPolyline *polyline = [[GMSPolyline alloc] init];
GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];

NSArray * points = [self calculateRoutesFrom:source to:dest];

NSInteger numberOfSteps = points.count;

for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numberOfSteps; index++)
{
    CLLocation *location = [points objectAtIndex:index];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
    [path addCoordinate:coordinate];
}

polyline.path = path;
polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
polyline.strokeWidth = 2.f;
polyline.map = self.mapView;

// Copy the previous polyline, change its color, and mark it as geodesic.
polyline = [polyline copy];
polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
polyline.geodesic = YES;
polyline.map = self.mapView;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self loadMapViewWithDirection];   
}
```

Comment: Integrate what? SDKDemo source file or bundle

Comment: You need to add GoogleMaps.framework and SDKDemos is demo app for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer [this code](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions/downloads), it does exactly what you want.
EDIT: and [this also](https://github.com/Surya121/SBMapWithRoute/downloads)

Comment: Yup i have seen both.. They are using Google API.. But i am trying to do this without using Google API. Is there any possibility??

Comment: Where i can get that Google API files??

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this locally. Implementing an algoritm for finding a path between two gps points requires a lot of input data (data from the maps) and you don't have this. Only a map provider can afford to implement such algoritm and expose an API for using it. I think `Google` have routing `API`, but I haven't played around with it...

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Note that the TOS say that you have to display the results on a Google map, so you'll have to disable the functionality on the next iOS release