# How can I get the turn by turn direction between 2 pins in map in iOS5?

Tags: ios, maps, latitude-longitude

In my app i implemented the maps .Using latitude and longitude values dropped the pins.But i need to get the turn by turn directions between 2 pins .How can i get the direction between 2 pins(annotations) in map?

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the documentation of google maps api web service.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

It is given very clear step by step in it.
They have even given an example of what you are trying to achive
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel

steps:
1. Create a UIWebView to display map.
2. Create an html file of name "maps.html" in a folder name "HTML" and copy the code given in the documentation
3. Call the html file from your objective-c class by
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"maps" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"HTML"]]]];

Answer (score 0):

To draw path between two locations,
[Finding Path/Route Between two points on MapKit in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002857/790794) will help you.

To retrive list of locations between given two 2 pins, you have to use google map api
http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=&daddr=