# Is there an alternative for showing a route for more that two placemarks using MKMapKit in iOS6?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, routes, mapkit

Until iOS6, it was possible to use Google Maps API with optimize waypoints parameter for showing an optimized route between many locations. The route on map was shown on UIWebView or in Safari. With iOS6 everything has changed: Apple Map Kit now uses Apple maps, so its illegal to use Google Maps API in it. Currently, MKMapItem allows to call and pass [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html). However, currently it allows to use only two locations. Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

Their is a open source class files RegexkitLite that use to find path between two places
follow this [documentation for implementation](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/index.html).
please go through this it solve your problem.

[

Comment: I cannot find anything in RegexkitLite documentation about calculating  path between locations. Is it correct reference?

Comment: http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/index.html this is direct link to regexkit documentation which include documentation. i used it in my app to finding & displaying path between two locations

Comment: you may also go through this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002179/finding-path-route-between-two-points-on-mapkit-in-iphone

Comment: The problem is google maps API can be used in google maps only. Apple uses Apple maps in iOS6. Thanks, but I am looking for iOS6 compliant solution.