# how to pass custom routes in ios maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am facing a small problem in an iOS app. I am creating a small app for iPad in which user can get directions from one location to another, but we want to display our custom routes on map which we have created using an algo.

Is it possible in any way ? I dont have problem in switching to native app but I want it to be loaded with custom maps.

Is there any way to do it or any tutorial to do so.

I do not want to use MTDirectionKit.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the [following link](http://iosrider.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/draw-route-between-two-location/) for the source code , how to draw routes between two locations.

Hope it will help you

Comment: thanks but this draws route from one location to another but what I want is to pass start location, end location and custom intermediate location, and the route should go from all these points.

Comment: go through this url . it is calculating the route between the two points using Google Direction API , where you can easily pass the midpoint and the APIs will accordingly provide you the Directions , and further you can draw the route on MapView . link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002179/finding-path-route-between-two-points-on-mapkit-in-iphone