# How to show the path between two location in mapkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, mapkit

I want to show two location's distance in mapkit, I have tried my process its not showing the distance between the location. tried below codes its not working, can any one help me in coding.

```
MKMapView *   mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 294, 320, 122)];
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
mapView.delegate = self;
MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
 MKPlacemark *placemark1 = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(9.9176458, 78.1228237) addressDictionary:nil];
[request setSource:[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark1]];

MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(13.0475604, 80.2089535) addressDictionary:nil];
request.destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];


// [request setDestination:myMapItem];
    [request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile]; // This can be limited to automobile and walking directions.
    [request setRequestsAlternateRoutes:YES]; // Gives you several route options.
    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (MKRoute *route in [response routes]) {
                [mapView addOverlay:[route polyline] level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads]; // Draws the route above roads, but below labels.
                // You can also get turn-by-turn steps, distance, advisory notices, ETA, etc by accessing various route properties.
            }
        }
    }];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];



- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay
{
    MKPolylineRenderer *renderer =
    [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    renderer.lineWidth = 5.0;
    return renderer;
}
```

Please any help me .

Comment: Apple MapKit (which the code is using) is not Google Maps.  Directions are not available for _all_ locations.  The completion handler gives you an `error` object.  If it's not `nil` then you should at least NSLog it (like in Jakub's answer) to see what the problem might be (basic debugging like this is better than just saying "it's not working").  For certain parts of the world, you may have to use alternate sources for directions.

Answer (score 1):

If you check `error` in the `-calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:`

```
[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (MKRoute *route in [response routes]) {
            [mapView addOverlay:[route polyline] level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads]; // Draws the route above roads, but below labels.
            // You can also get turn-by-turn steps, distance, advisory notices, ETA, etc by accessing various route properties.
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];
```

You will probably see

> Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=5 "Directions Not Available" UserInfo=0x7fefe3bb5660 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=A route to the nearest road cannot be determined., MKErrorGEOError=-403, MKDirectionsErrorCode=6, NSLocalizedDescription=Directions Not Available}

Which means that it is not possible to calculate directions from given location.

Comment: you can try: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002179/finding-path-route-between-two-points-on-mapkit-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code; I use CLLocationManager Delegate to compute distance between two location and MKMapView Delegate. here is my code, it may help you.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)location{
float distance = 0.0f;
NSMutableArray *locationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (CLLocation *newLocation in location) {
    [locationArray addObject:newLocation];
}

for (int i = 0 ; i < locationArray.count; i++) {
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locationArray objectAtIndex:i];
    distance += [newLocation distanceFromLocation:[locationArray objectAtIndex:i+1]];
}         
NSLog(@"%f",distance);
CLLocationCoordinate2D cordinates [locationsArray.count];
MKPolyline *userLocationsPolyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:cordinates count:locationsArray.count];
[userMapView setDelegate:self];
[userMapView addOverlay:userLocationsPolyLine];
```

}

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{    
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]){
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
        renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        renderer.lineWidth   = 3;
        return renderer;
    }
    return nil;
}
```