# Google Map iOS Sdk with Navigation Speech

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, navigation

I want to use Google map speech navigation in my app. But i am not able to find out anything regarding that. I checked out many thing in google but none provide me the thing i require. Is their anyway i can use google map speech navigation in iOS without Google map Application in device. I need to use navigation in my app only not in google map.

Thanks in advance friends

Answer (score 0):

The google map ios Sdk does not have any turn-by-turn navigation api or navigation api's yet.

Please refer link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme for custom url schema features.

Comment: so if i need to implement the voice navigation then ?

Comment: you  can't. But you can set path between  Source & Destination .

Comment: okey thanks buddy. can you provide me any link regarding that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002179/finding-path-route-between-two-points-on-mapkit-in-iphone

Comment: https://github.com/ManoMarks/demos/tree/master/DirectionsAPIAsync
Demo app for google map routes.

And you can get all information provided in this iOS app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/inroute-intelligent-route/id703796787?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

//MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id )overlay
  {
  MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;

  ```
    MKPolylineView  * _routeLineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc]                   initWithPolyline:self.routeLine] autorelease];
      _routeLineView.fillColor = #COLOR;
     _routeLineView.strokeColor = #COLOR;
    _routeLineView.lineWidth = 15;
      _routeLineView.lineCap = kCGLineCapSquare;


      overlayView = _routeLineView;

      return overlayView;
  ```

}

Than 
CLLocationCoordinate2D newcordinate =   Source.coordinate;

CLLocationCoordinate2D oldcordinate =   destination.coordinate;

```
   MKMapPoint * pointsArray =
           malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)*2);

       pointsArray[0]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(oldcordinate); 
       pointsArray[1]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(newcordinate);    

        MKPolyline *  routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsArray count:2];
       free(pointsArray);

        [MapView addOverlay:routeLine];
```