# How to get direction from current location to an address (in TableView)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, dictionary, direction

I have a tableView like the image below

[image]

When I click City A, a tableView shows up with addresses

[image]

What I want is, when I click Address A, a ViewController shows up with a MapView in it. The MapView shows the direction from the current location to the Address A.

I have already get Current Location by using the code:

`var locationManager = CLLocationManager()`

and in ViewDidLoad:

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true }
```

So, what should I do next to get direction from current location to Address A?

And one more question, suppose I have a label under the line "Address A", how can I show the distance between current location and address A in that label?
Thank you.

BTW:
I have "Intermediate iOS Programming with Swift.pdf" with MapKit and direction and a lot of stuff, but the code in that pdf just didn't work. That's why I'm here. Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Getting directions and showing them on the map is pretty well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002857/1857279).

Getting the distance between two points requires that they are both `CLLocation`'s and then you just use:

```
CLLocationDistance dist = [loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2];
```

Comment: Thanks Fennelouski. But the code in the link you sent me is in Objective-C, right? I study Swift and know nothing about objective-C